# Dependencies while installing wine-stable-i386:i386, but they are already installed

Tags: package-management, wine, dependencies

I try to install wine on ubuntu 18.04 by following https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu. The dependencies all cascade down to

> wine-stable-i386:i386 : Dependencies: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is installed

However when I try to install it returns

> libc6:i386 is already installed in the version (2.27-3ubuntu1)

How do I resolve this?

Comment: And btw when running `sudo apt-get -f install`, there are no errors

Comment: try to check your depends using `sudo apt-cache policy wine-stable-i386:i386`, please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1099826/edit) your question including that output!

Answer (score 0):

it requires the 2.28 version of libc6-i368 while downloading it with `sudo apt-get install libc6-i386` provides the 2.27 version for Ubuntu 18.04

I noticed that 2.28 version is available on Ubuntu 18.10